# Web server for python

Tags: python-3.x, webserver

I am very new to Python and I knew the basic programming in Python. Can anyone please tell me how to develop a web application in python. I want know what is the web server or localhost for python application( as wamp server in case of PHP).

Answer (score 0):

If you have worked your way through something such as [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveinto.org/python3/) then have a look at the [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) module for Python 2 or the [httpserver module](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/http.server.html?highlight=http.server#http.server) in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

> A Web server is a program that, using the client/server model and the
>   World Wide Web's Hypertext Transfer Protocol ( HTTP ), serves the
>   files that form Web pages to Web users (whose computers contain HTTP
>   clients that forward their requests).

There are several webservers which can be used for Python.Selecting the webservers play a crucial role as it can vary features from one server to another.

For Developing python applications tutorials are available at google,kindly have a thorough research before posting questions other than errors / exceptions.

More on webservers are available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-comparison-of-web-servers-for-python-based-web-applications).